# Extract list of tickers bloomberg api

Tags: fixed-income, programming, bloomberg

Does anyone know what is the python equivalent to the BQL.Query/BSRCH functions from the Excel API?

I am essentially trying to get a list of tickers for all government bonds from a certain country from bloomberg, to then get various elements from it (mainly Z_SPRD, coupon, maturity and yield)

Currently have installed blpapi and tia.

I'm fairly new to bloomberg and its API and struggling to set it up. If you have any good documentation or videos explaining how to use it  would be welcome. I've already went through the 'core developer guide' but has not made things much clearer.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily an API programming query best directed towards bloomberg support and is not a direct quant finance query.